# Where can I find detailed information on industrial applications of the boolean satisfiability problem (SAT) in the car industry?

Tags: logic, reference-request, applications, satisfiability

Where can I find detailed information on industrial applications of the boolean satisfiability problem (SAT) in the car industry? This article http://www.carstensinz.de/talks/RISC-2005.pdf presents the case of the configuration of DC’s Mercedes Cars but does not provide enough details. I am looking for  a more detailed explanation of this case or of similar industrial applications of SAT related to operations research.